# How do I get the font scaling factor from cli?

Tags: command-line, fonts, dconf, gsettings

How do I get the font scaling factor in Ubuntu? I need to find the appropriate way to get this value for Gnome, KDE and other systems. I need to know which function to call in order to obtain this value.
Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, but from what language are you calling? Languages might have their own libraries to communicate with dconf/gsettings.

Comment: I am using Vala and I found out that that GSettings is available in the GLib API.

Comment: Exactly! Will add that to the answer, together with the python option later if I get home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```

You can usually find out the dconf key of these settings by running in a terminal:

```
dconf watch /
```

...and play with the settings you want to get. The corresponding dconf key will show.

The gsettings api is also available in the GLib library (look for GSettings in the manual).